# How to generate working xorg.conf for intel driver

Tags: linux, xorg

I am struggling to get a multi-monitor setup working on an Optimus laptop running Fedora 25. Right now, I'm trying to create an xorg.conf file that sets VirtualHeads > 0.

The X server starts up ok if I run it without an xorg.conf file at all, or if I run with a commented-out file dropped into xorg.conf.d. But if I put anything that specifies the intel driver, it says No devices found. For example:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

That's enough to prevent it from working.

I tried running (without having any config files) Xorg -configure, but that seg faults before it manages to write out the file.

Comment: So, are you sure you have hardware that works with the `intel` driver in the first place? What does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` say without `xorg.conf`? Note that some newer Intel graphics cards only work with the modesetting driver.

Comment: Whoa... ok, I've never understood the whole 'modesetting driver' thing. You could be right, the log says it's loading the intel driver (along with several others eg vesa), but I'm not sure it's actually using it. And if I use Driver "modesetting", it does come up. Except it's all black?

Comment: Oh. It's just a black background. It's there, and live. Thanks! Now to see if it's possible to use intel-virtual-output or something to talk to it...

Comment: Would you be so kind as to share your xorg.conf with us ?

Comment: After many iterations, I finally ended up switching to the nvidia proprietary driver, plus the modesetting driver for the intel chip. The main config snippet that is relevant appears to be /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nividia.conf: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9027099